# Declaring and appending a list within a dictionary in one line

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering if there is a command for a dictionary that allows me to declare a key and list if it isn't already in the dictionary, or update it if it is.

```
i = 0
newlines["numbersbytwo"] = []
newlines["numbersbyfive"] = []
while i<n:
    newlines["numbersbytwo"].append(i*2)
    newlines["numbersbyfive"].append(i*5)
    i+=1
```

This is my code at the minute, but I was wondering if there is any way of not having to declare it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) method.

```
>>> newlines = {}
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < n:
>>>    newlines.setdefault(numbersbytwo, [])
>>>    newlines.setdefault(numbersbyfive, [])
>>>    newlines['numbersbytwo'].append(i*2)
>>>    newlines['numbersbyfive'].append(i*5)
>>>    i += 1
```

Comment: The `update` part is going to overwrite the lists with integers, right?

Comment: You can also move the `append` lines right after `setdefault` - it returns the value by default meaning you can `setdefault(key, []).append()` right away.

Comment: Thanks @kroolik for the tips. I never used this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) with empty list as default value. For example:

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: newlines = defaultdict(list)

In [3]: newlines["numbersbytwo"].append(1)

In [4]: newlines["numbersbyfive"].append(11)

In [5]: newlines
Out[5]: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00000000031D5048>, {'numbersbyfive': [11], 'numbersbytwo': [1]})

In [6]: newlines["numbersbytwo"]
Out[6]: [1]

In [7]: newlines["numbersbyfive"]
Out[7]: [11]

In [8]:
```

Comment: A simple `defaultdict(list)` would do.

Comment: You are right, I removed lambda, thanks... It is more readable this way.